# Member of non-managed class cannot be a handle

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am trying to setup an SQL connection using SqlClient in c++.

I have encountered the following error

> "a member of a non-managed class cannot be a handle"

```
    #using <mscorlib.dll>
    #using <System.dll>
    #using <System.Data.dll>
    #using <System.Xml.dll>
    using namespace std;

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

    class CConnection {

    public:
    SqlConnection ^connection=gcnew SqlConnection();

    CConnection(String^,String^);

    void close();
    void connect(String^,String^);
    bool isConnected();
    SqlConnection getCon();

    ~CConnection();

};
```

The error occurs at the following line `SqlConnection connection=gcnew SqlConnection();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You declared `CConnection` as an unmanged class by using only the `class` keyword. However, `CConnection` makes heavy use of managed features: It has a member of type `SqlConnection`, which is a managed class, and you used handles (`^`) instead of a pointers (`*`) in the class. You may want to declare `CConnection` to be a managed class by using [`ref class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699870.aspx) instead of only `class`.